# ASP classic generate correct DOCTYPE for pure SVG document

Tags: asp-classic, svg, internet-explorer-9, mime, doctype

Trying to get the correct DOCTYPE on a pure SVG document that is inside an XML prolog I think they call it.  My SVG works great in Firefox, but trying to port it to IE9 there are no end of problems.  The content in the IE DOM turns out completely different than FF, it's really really strange.  Some Javascript that is triggered when the SVG objects load seems to trigger "too early" i.e. before the preceeding elements are present.

Could DOCTYPE be an issue?

According to some IE9 and SVG info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589526(v=vs.85).aspx I think what I'm trying to do with IE9, is use "standalone SVG" as in the approach where the server serves up a document with a .svg extension.  EXCEPT, the SVG in question is being genned by a server running ASP classic.

Some of the ASP commands affecting the response coming back to the browser are:
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "inline"
    Response.ContentType = "image/svg+xml"

Another wrinkle, I'm using MSXML XSLT transforms to gen the ouput. So I'm limited to what and when the XSLT serializer is capable of doing.

The recommended content in the file is something like:

I'd like to leave out the html part entirely and just have the XML prolog, DOCTYPE, then the first root element .

Is DOCTYPE strictly necessary with IE9 for SVG?  I think 'm having trouble getting the server to issue one, in the correct sequence.  If it even matters for a "pure SVG" document.

Answer (score 0):

If your svg is not "embedded" in a (X)HTML page but has `<svg>` as a root element, then you shouldn't need a DOCTYPE. (SVG itself doesn't require one, but a browser might.) Even some SVG WG members [have advised](http://www.mail-archive.com/svg-developers@yahoogroups.com/msg03073.html) not to use a DOCTYPE with svg.

Using `version` and `baseProfile` attributes might fix some rendering issues.

If you decide to use a DOCTYPE, you can copy appropriate one from here http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html scroll down to heading "Optional doctype declarations"